# How to connect http server websocket with ssl using vertx?

Tags: ssl, openssl, vert.x, vertx-httpclient

I have created two classes server and client. Server starting with ssl as below

```
HttpServer server =
  vertx.createHttpServer(new HttpServerOptions().setSsl(true).setKeyStoreOptions(
    new JksOptions().setPath("server-keystore.jks").setPassword("wibble")
  ));
```

Also one more i.e. client

```
vertx.createHttpClient(new HttpClientOptions().setSsl(true)).getNow(4443, "localhost", "/", resp -> {
      System.out.println("Got response " + resp.statusCode());
      resp.bodyHandler(body -> System.out.println("Got data " + body.toString("ISO-8859-1")));
    });
```

While running both On client I am getting "Failed to create SSL connection". Is there any way to configure anything related to ssl?

Comment: If I write .setTrustAll(true) it connect. but that is threat. So How can I connect without trusting all.

Comment: Add your certificate to the `TrustOptions` or use a valid certificate for your server http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_client_trust_configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To enable ssl in vertx you can use [keystore.jks](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-auth-jwt/js/) file

Then use following configuration :

```
HttpServerOptions secureOptions = new HttpServerOptions();
    if (Configuration.SSL_enabled) {
        LOG.debug("Secure Transport Protocol [ SSL/TLS ] has been enabled !!! ");
        secureOptions.setSsl(true)
                .setKeyStoreOptions(new JksOptions().setPath(Configuration.SSL_filename)
                        .setPassword(Configuration.SSL_password))
                .setTrustStoreOptions(new JksOptions().setPath(Configuration.SSL_filename)
                        .setPassword(Configuration.SSL_password))
                .addEnabledSecureTransportProtocol(Constants.TLS_VERSION_1)
                .addEnabledSecureTransportProtocol(Constants.TLS_VERSION_2);

    }

   vertx.createHttpServer(secureOptions).requestHandler(router::accept).listen(Configuration.port);
```

> I hope this will help you :)